# How to match a symbol with a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an array that contains both string and symbol

In my function I am getting a string to check if the array contains that or not.

```
array = ["day",:night]

def check(name)
    if array.include? name or array.include? name.to_sym
         return true
    else
         return false
   end
end
```

If the input is "day" it returns `true`. If the input is "night" it returns `false`. I want to return `true` in case of "night" as I converted this to check if a symbol with the same name exists.

How can I make this function work so that it compares a symbol (`:night`) with a string (`"night"`) and returns `true`?

Comment: Perhaps you want `array.map(&:to_s).include?(name.to_s)`.

Comment: Yup it worked. Thanks

Comment: don't hesitate to mark the question answered by Cary.

Answer (score 5):

```
def check(name, array)
  array.map(&:to_s).include?(name.to_s)
end

array = ["day",:night]

check("day", array)   #=> true
check(:day, array)    #=> true
check("night", array) #=> true
check(:night, array)  #=> true
check("cat", array)   #=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your array into your method definition like so:

```
def check(name)
  array = ["day",:night]
  array.include? name.to_s or array.include? name.to_sym  
end

p check("day") #=> true
p check(:day) #=> true
p check("night") #=> true
p check("hyperspace") #=> false
```

Comment: You don't need to have an if statement. Just return the result of the check.